# How do I install a "Lite in the Box" (brand) faucet?

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I have a [Lite In the Box kitchen faucet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004I1UXG8) that provides two flexible supply tubes for attaching to water supply. These supply tubes have two o-rings on the faucet end and are attached last in the installation process since the mounting adapter is too small in diameter to allow the tubes to pass through. The pictures from the company web site show the tubes being installed last into the mounted faucet that must have been hand tightened.

Given this problem and no experience with supply tubes like these I want to be sure I understand the installation and that these sorts of tubes will not leak using the installation method. There is a requirement for an adapter to attach these tubes to the existing plumbing which is separate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is very standard mixer tap setup. Basically you run the flexible piping through all the holes etc that you need to do to connect it to the main. You do this before you have fixed the mixer in place. Then, you feed the two small ends up through the mounting hole on the kitchen sink and screw them in.

There will be a long bolt with a slot for a flat-headed screwdriver. Make sure that is installed as well (tighten with a screwdriver so it's tight).

Then you put the mixer with the three attachments (the two flexible pipes and the threaded bolt) flush with the basin, and facing in the correct direction.

Then, using a [tube spanner](https://www.google.com.au/search?safe=off&q=tube%20spanner&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.50952593,d.aGc,pv.xjs.s.en_US.epv7Gxs5zsU.O&biw=2016&bih=1206&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=bjoTUvvxM4ejigfNv4DwBw) (available at any hardware store) you screw in a butterfly fitting and the nut from beneath. This will hold the mixer tight against the bench top. A tube wrench is important because otherwise it's typically impractical to do up the nut tightly, due to limited space and the length of the bolt.

Comment: The faucet has a large plastic tube that threads into the mixer as shown in the picture; there is no butterfly fitting and the tube appears to be designed for hand tightening. I think that piece also subs for the threaded bolt. The supply tubes were my major concern since there is no way to get a wrench onto the tube to tighten them and just getting them started looks to be a problem. Your advice is good for standard faucets but this particular one is different from those I have seen.